# Configuring AirPort Extreme with Existing Router

Tags: network, wifi, airport

I'm setting up an office network consisting of:
- ATT ADSL2 Modem -> CISCO Router (198.x.x.x) -> Airport Extreme

[image]

I'm having an issue getting the Airport Extreme (6th Gen) to connect to the network. I want to use the AE to serve its own 5Ghz and 2.5Ghz network. The issue isn't configuring the wireless details - it is how to get the airport to connect to the router correctly.

Upon connecting the AE as a fresh factory default device, it reports:
[image]

What is the correct method to setting up the Airport Extreme in this instance?
I've tried the roaming setup on Apple with no success.

Comment: without knowing the specifics of the airport, I'd see if it has an Access Point mode; I'd guess currently you have 2 devices on the network both wanting to be DHCP servers

Comment: Is the AT&T router set to be cascaded mode to the Cisco router?

Comment: I believe so...which is why it's part of the network. I would like to eventually remove

Comment: i doubt that the ATT-Modem is a router. What's the name of the product?

Comment: My issue was a faulty ethernet cable between the 1st router and Airport. Swapping it out and setting it up as a non-bridged DHCP only device worked.

Answer (score 1):

The airport extreme should be connected as just a device with the cisco router handling DHCP and NAT.  in the airport configuration go to the Network Tab and click the double headed arrow under Router Mode set it to "Off(Bridged Mode)
[image]

You can then go to Wireless and set that how ever you want all traffic will go to the cisco router and either be forwarded to the Internet or go to the voip, printer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your Airport Extreme has a link-local address.

[Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address)

> For Internet Protocol (IP) networks, they are assigned most often using stateless address autoconfiguration. In IPv4 they are normally only used to assign IP addresses to network interfaces when no external, stateful mechanism of address configuration exists, such as the Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP), or when another primary configuration method has failed.
>   Link-local addresses for IPv4 are defined in the address block 169.254.0.0/16

Just enter the setup and manually configure an IP-address for the ethernet interface of the `Airport Extreme` in the same [private address range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) as the ethernet interface in the Cisco router.

Example:
If the IP-address of the ethernet interface (Cisco Router) is 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 assign 192.168.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 to the ethernet interface (Airport Extreme)

Comment: This works to an extent... The AE now reports no DNS servers and no connection to the internet. After setting DNS to 8.8.8.8 - googles servers, i still get a disconnected state...

Comment: the gateway address - if necessary - is the ethernet address of the cisco router.